# Data extention - Trailhead - Clarification on DATA RETENTION

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, trailhead

I came with a question, where in one the answer regarding the DATA RETENTION is as below [as per trailhead!!!]

**You cannot remove the configured data retention settings once you configure them!**

But, I am pretty much confident this is NOT correct, as I am able to,
- Turn off/on again
- Change the date of Data deletion
- Even change the option from "All records and data extensions" TO "Individual Records"

Correct me if I am wrong and does the above highlighted statement as per trailhead is correct?

FYI: Trailhead module link [https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-contact-management/manage-contact-data?trail_id=develop-for-marketing-cloud]

Comment: It is outdated. There was a recent update (a couple months I think?) to data retention that now let's you change it after it being set in UI. They likely just didnt update it yet on trailhead

Comment: Thanks for the info @Gortonington ... please add it as an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Trailhead is outdated, which is why it is stating incorrect info. There was a recent update (a couple months I think?) to data retention capabilities that now let's you change it after it being set in UI. They likely just didn't update it yet on Trailhead, but I am sure it will be handled at some point.